# Interpreting GA4 "select_item" event

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, google-datalayer

I am trying to decide what constitutes a `select_item` event.  There are three different outcomes when an item within an `item_list` is clicked on:

1. The item is immediately added to **cart** (already an `add_to_cart` event).
2. The browser is redirected to the **product page** (firing a `view_item` event).
3. A **preview** of the product page opens in a modal (also a `view_item` event?).

Which of these is considered selecting an item?

Comment: We had this same discussion. Google’s documentation is indeed vague. In case #2, `select_item` should be fired _on click_ in the product listing. `view_item` should then be fired _on load_ of the product detail page. I think case #3 is just an in-situ variant of that. For #1, I wouldn’t expect this event being fired at all. There’s also case #4, where you can select multiple products from a listing e.g. with checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/ecommerce?client_type=gtm#select_item-gtm) on `select_item`, when a user is viewing a list of items and "selects" one of them, this is when they recommend the event to fire. There is also a [list of recommended parameters](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/reference/events?client_type=gtm#select_item) to pass along.

In order examples, I think it more closely follows #3 maybe, with the `view_item` once a user views the actual product page.

Comment: So if each item in the list has three links - preview, details, buy - you think only the preview click should count as a select_item event?

Comment: That's would be how I implement it. Details I would reserve for view, and buy I would assume is adding to a cart. That only leaves the preview as the select.

Comment: Agree with @A_Patterson I wouldn't use details + preview for the simplicity of the experience. If you are viewing a product in a list, it used to be already a preview. Also, buy could be add to cart or begin checkout.